# Erro criação Foreign key MariaDB

Tags: mysql, script, mariadb

Olá, estou criando as seguintes tabelas no meu banco de dados MariaDB:

```
 CREATE TABLE `compras`
    (
      `id` int PRIMARY KEY,
      `aberto_por` int,
      `titulo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `empresa` int NOT NULL,
      `orcamento` int NOT NULL,
      `forma_pagamento` int NOT NULL COMMENT '1 - vista / 2 - parcelado',
      `parcelas` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
      `valor_parcelas` double,
      `sub_total` double NOT NULL,
      `desconto` double,
      `total` double NOT NULL,
      `finalidade` text NOT NULL,
      `uso` text NOT NULL,
      `local` text NOT NULL,
      `fornecedores` text,
      `id_sap` int,
      `criado_em` datetime NOT NULL,
      `duvidas` varchar(255)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE `compras_status`
    (
      `id` int PRIMARY KEY,
      `id_situacao` int NOT NULL,
      `id_compra` int NOT NULL,
      `id_usuario` int NOT NULL,
      `informacoes` varchar(255),
      `data` datetime NOT NULL
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE `compras_situacao`
    (
      `id` int PRIMARY KEY,
      `descricao` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE `compras_anexos`
    (
      `id` int PRIMARY KEY,
      `id_compra` int,
      `nome_arquivo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `tipo_anexo` int
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE `compras_avaliadores`
    (
      `id` int PRIMARY KEY,
      `id_avaliador` int,
      `id_compra` int,
      `id_centrocusto` int,
      `aprovado` int DEFAULT 0
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE `membros`
    (
      `id` int PRIMARY KEY
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE `compras_itens`
    (
      `id` int PRIMARY KEY,
      `id_compra` int,
      `descricao` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `quantidade` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `valor_unitario` double NOT NULL,
      `total_item` double NOT NULL
    );
    
    ALTER TABLE `compras` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`aberto_por`) REFERENCES `membros` (`id`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `compras_status` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_situacao`) REFERENCES `compras_situacao` (`id`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `compras_status` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_compra`) REFERENCES `compras` (`id`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `compras_status` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `membros` (`id`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `compras_anexos` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_compra`) REFERENCES `compras` (`id`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `compras_avaliadores` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_avaliador`) REFERENCES `membros` (`id`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `compras_avaliadores` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_compra`) REFERENCES `compras` (`id`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `compras_itens` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_compra`) REFERENCES `compras` (`id`);
```

Lembrando que a tabela membros já está criada.
Quando mando executar, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> ## 1005 - Não pode criar a tabela `sistemapib`.`compras_anexos` (erro no. 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

O que poderia ser? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Acho que o compas_anexos.id_compra deve ser not null

Comment: Esse erro pode aparecer em diversos erros, use o comando `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` para ter mais detalhes do problema.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, porém nenhuma delas resolveu, o problema persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Como boa prática, é sempre importante marcar como `UNSIGNED` as colunas de ID, evitando problemas relacionados à números negativos.

Experimente a seguinte query de criação:

```
CREATE TABLE `compras`
(
  `id` int UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  `aberto_por` int,
  `titulo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `empresa` int NOT NULL,
  `orcamento` int NOT NULL,
  `forma_pagamento` int NOT NULL COMMENT '1 - vista / 2 - parcelado',
  `parcelas` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `valor_parcelas` double,
  `sub_total` double NOT NULL,
  `desconto` double,
  `total` double NOT NULL,
  `finalidade` text NOT NULL,
  `uso` text NOT NULL,
  `local` text NOT NULL,
  `fornecedores` text,
  `id_sap` int,
  `criado_em` datetime NOT NULL,
  `duvidas` varchar(255)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `compras_status`
(
  `id` int UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_situacao` int NOT NULL,
  `id_compra` int NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int NOT NULL,
  `informacoes` varchar(255),
  `data` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `compras_situacao`
(
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY,
  `descricao` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `compras_anexos`
(
  `id` int UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_compra` int,
  `nome_arquivo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_anexo` int
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `compras_avaliadores`
(
  `id` int UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_avaliador` int,
  `id_compra` int,
  `id_centrocusto` int,
  `aprovado` int DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `membros`
(
  `id` int UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `compras_itens`
(
  `id` int UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_compra` int,
  `descricao` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `quantidade` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `valor_unitario` double NOT NULL,
  `total_item` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `compras` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`aberto_por`) REFERENCES `membros` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `compras_status` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_situacao`) REFERENCES `compras_situacao` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `compras_status` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_compra`) REFERENCES `compras` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `compras_status` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `membros` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `compras_anexos` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_compra`) REFERENCES `compras` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `compras_avaliadores` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_avaliador`) REFERENCES `membros` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `compras_avaliadores` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_compra`) REFERENCES `compras` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `compras_itens` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_compra`) REFERENCES `compras` (`id`);
```